# How do I fix a "Performance counter registry hive consistency" when installing SQL Server R2 Express?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-express

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from this site:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/

I have a 64-bit, Windows 7 machine.

I have tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions but each fail on "Performance counter registry hive consistency".

**How can I fix this so that I can install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?**

[image]

Answer (score 65):

You can skip the Performance counter check in the setup altogether:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck
```

Comment: Just for clarity: Everything after .exe are options. If the setup file is called e.g. `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` then you should run the program from the command line as `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck`

Answer (score 16):

Use Rafael's solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/dddf0349-557b-48c7-bf82-6bd1adb5c694..

**Added data from link to avoid link rot..**

put this at any Console application:

> string.Format("{0,3}", CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.Parent.LCID.ToString("X")).Replace(" ", "0");

Watch the result. At mine it was "016".

Then you go to the registry at this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib
```

and create another one with the name you got from the string.Format result.

In my case:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\016"
```

and copy the info that is on any other key in this Perflib to this key you just created. Run the instalation again.

Just run the script and get your 3 digit code. Then follow his simple and quick steps, and you're ready to go!

Cheers

Comment: It is a C# console application

Comment: You could also use Linqpad or Visual studio Code

Answer (score 14):

I had this same problem. For me this solution worked for **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express**.

1. Create a shortcut for `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` (This is the name of the
   file I used)
2. Right-click on the shortcut and click "Properties"
3. Look for a box under the shortcut tab that says "Target"
4. Inside of the target box, add to whatever is already in there this
   line:

> /Action=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck

Of course this does not fix the underlying issue but it is a workaround because this fix also works on the principle of skipping the Performance counter check in the setup. The difference is this method worked for me when doing it through the command line failed.

Answer (score 8):

I had the perf counter reg issue and here's what I did.

1. My exe file was SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
2. In command line typed in the below line and hit enter

> C:\Projects\Installer\SQL Server 2008 Management Studio\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck

(Note : i had the exe in this location of my machine C:\Projects\Installer\SQL Server 2008 Management Studio)

3. SQL Server installation started and this time it skipped the rule for Perf counter registry values. The installation was successful.

Answer (score 5):

open Command line  and
type **lodctr /r**
The p. counter will be resotred\recreated.

There is no need to skip it.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774958.aspx

Comment: This is the solution on multiple sources, but still didn't help me.  The registry edit (described terribly above, but better on other sites, also didn't work)  The location wasn't the issue either.  The only working solution was to use the skiprule switch.

Comment: Make sure you use lodctr /R with uppercase R & retry the command from SysWOW64 directory. src: https://github.com/JimmyAppelt/Snaz/wiki/Solving-warning-or-error-within-System-Info

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the check results in a corrupted install.
This is the only solution that worked for me:

1. Create a C# console app with the following code:
    `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,3}", CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.Parent.LCID.ToString("X")).Replace(" ", "0"));`
2. Run the app and get the 3 digit code.
3. Run > Regedit, open the following path:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib

Now, if you don't have a folder underneath that path with the 3 digit code from step 2, create it.
If you do have the folder, check that it has the "Counter" and "Help" values set under that path.
It probably doesn't -- which is why the check fails.

Create the missing Counter and Help keys (REG_MULTI_SZ). For the values, copy them from the existing path above (probably 009).

The check should now pass.

Comment: Awesome find! Curious to know how did you find this ?!!

Comment: Thanks! Just by browsing various Microsoft forums, comparing the registry entries from different installs and working it out. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Click on Start and type in CMD
Right click and click on Run as administrator
Then from C:\windows\system32 type 
lodctr /R:PerfStringBackup.INI 

and press Enter
then restart the compurter and retry!
```

Answer (score 1):

`<sqlserverdir>\setup.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck`

Above worked for me... I did installed it, from my external, using command line  interface.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me, you can try it:

- Write to run : regedit
- Then open

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> Perflib
- Under the /009 and /01F files, right click and select new and choose
  "multi string value" named it as "Counter" and do these steps again
  to create "Help" named file. (Important!! it is case sensitive)
- Copy contents of "Counter" and "Help" files under the
  "CurrentLanguage" to the /009 and /01F files.

Answer (score 0):

Save the execution file on your desktop
Make sure you note the name of your file 
Go to start and 
type cmd 
right click on it

select run as administrator press enter

then you something  below

**C:\Users\your computer name\Desktop>**

If you are seeing

C:\Windows\system32>

make sure you change it using CD

type the name of your file

**C:\Users\your computer name\Desktop>the name of the file your copy.exe/ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck**

Answer (score -2):

Well guys, the solution to the problem is the following:

1. click in: Start
2. write the word: ejecut
3. After, write: regedit
4. Open the directory: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
5. SOFTWARE
6. Microsoft
7. Windows NT
8. CurrentVersion
9. Perflib
10. Check the following things:

1) Folder 00A:
2) Counter: the last number
3) Help: the last number

```
   Folder Perflib:
   Last Counter: 00A folder´s Counter 
   Last Help: 00A folder´s Help
```

Ready, verify the same number in both. success

Comment: Please clarify "1) Folder 00A: 2) Counter: the last number 3) Help: the last number".  What last number?  In my case, folder 00A has a counter with no value set.