# How do I fix Performance counter registry hive consistency " when installing SQL SERVER 2008 r2 in Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image: Snapshot]

Having this problem when trying to install SQL SERVER 2008 .. Need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Performance counter registry hive consistency" when installing SQL Server R2 Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476719/how-do-i-fix-a-performance-counter-registry-hive-consistency-when-installing-s)

Comment: Might this helps you : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774958.aspx